# Using PersistentFacesServlet and FacesServlet in the same war

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, icefaces

So I posted this question in the icefaces forum but didn't get much love, so I thought I would try here.

In my webapp I am using IceFaces for the bulk of the application but I want to use regular JSF for a mobile piece of the solution. I can't seem to get the IceFaces Servlet to 'let go' and let it concede to the regular FacesServlet. partial web.xml is below...

I have tried two different approaches 1) naming the mobile file as **fileName.mobile** and then also just trying http://myURL/AppName/mobile/ in hopes it would direct to the mobile path.

An interesting behavior I get when I just do http://myURL/AppName/fileName.mobile is that it receives an error
"javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /**fileName.xhtml** Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:136)
"

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mobile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mobile/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JustIce jars. Basically, the JustIce implementation of the Persistance faces servlet lives in harmony with other implementation of JSF. It should be as simple matter of replacing the IceFaces.jar with the JustIce.jar but since NetBeans handles this for me, I haven't had to check exactly in a while. :)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I already replaced the jar with the justice jar.  I'm going to go back and make sure I don't have the other jars cached or somewhere else... but justice.jar was in place before I posted.  I am curious how Netbeans handles this for you?

Comment: I told it I needed the IceFaces Framework, then I replaced the usual IceFaces RunTime library with the JUSTIce RunTime Library. I think I may have had to tweak my web.xml but I don't remember the steps I took.